# Whats the best way to find out if a value exists within a set of columns on the same table

Tags: php, mysql

Say I had a MySQL table which sorts relationships between users (where there is more than 2 columns of users). Whats the best way to check if a user exists in any of a set of columns within the table?

Heres a sample table:

```
user_relationships('id', 'team', 'teammember1', 'teammember2' 'teammember3' 'teammember4' 'teammember5' 'teammember6' 'teammember7' 'teammember8' 'teammember9');
```

Thanks in advance,
Ferdia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where teammmeber1=USER OR teammember2=USER OR teammember3=USER.........

I wouldn't make the table look like that...  But that's your decision

I would make it look like:

```
Table - Teams :
id,name,someotherinfo
Table - Team-Members :
team_id, user_id
```

Comment: Again that's just a sample, I cant post the real table here but its considerably more complex than a set of teammates :).

Comment: Is their really no way to define a column set to check?

Comment: True enough, i just figured there was a way to structure the query better. Fair enough. Cheers :)

Comment: +1 - the database needs normalising. You then get something like SELECT user_id FROM team_members WHERE team_id=X

Comment: again, no can do, that was just a hypothetical :)